# While loop with multiple OR conditions not exiting loop

Tags: c++

I am trying to run a while loop that runs when the input given is not equal to either "1" "2" or "3".

Below you can see the code:

```
string get_menu_choice()
{
    string option;
    cout << "What action would you like to perform?" << endl;
    cout << "1. View a room."       << endl
         << "2. Create a new room." << endl
         << "3. Delete a room."     << endl;

    cout << "Enter your choice: ";
    cin >> option;

    while (option != "1" || option != "2" || option != "3")
    {
        cout << "Invalid input, enter in only 1, 2 or 3!" << endl;
        cout << "Enter your choice: ";
        cin  >> option;
    }

    return option;
};
```

When I run this, it doesn't accept 1, 2 or 3 as an acceptable answer and keeps looping through

I have tried changing the statement to 
`while(options != ("1" || "2" || "3")){//code here}` however this also was unsuccessful for me.

Comment: Why do you want to change the working version you have provided in your post?

Comment: You need `&&` not `||`. However, you should make `option` an `int` and then write: `while ( option < 0 || option > 3 )`.

Comment: @Michielit doesnt work...

Comment: @DimChtz of course! thank you i have been staring at this for the past 20 min and I couldn't figure it out! Thanks!

Comment: @wtreston You're right, I was too fast and thought your aim was to avoid typing `option != ` three times.

Comment: Because you want to loop while `option` is different from 1 AND `option` is different from 2 AND `option` is different from 3. This are simple logic conditions. You want to get out of the loop when `option` is 1 OR `option` is 2 OR `option` is 3 (check De Morgan laws).

Comment: When comparing `option` with three distinct strings, it is guaranteed it won't be equal to at least one of them.    So you have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

you should code like below:

```
while(option != "1" && option != "2" && option != "3")
```